# Python: ValueError when inserting array into Mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, numpy, pymysql

I am trying to update multiple rows in a Mysql DB.
By reading around the most efficient solution seems to be a Bulk Insert with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement.
I have built the following array from numpy:

```
   update_list = [['11259761' '24' '15.169291741233783']
     ['15293357' '82' '0.5716360249451222']
     ['18833226' '56' '7.073284312907512']
     ...
     ['75212792' '55' '0.31338063342346445']
     ['75213202' '62' '0.1843318978715103']
     ['8295513' '45' '3.9280856957929116']]
```

Next, I am trying to isnert the list into mysql

```
con = pymysql.connect('connection settings here')
with con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = ("INSERT INTO properties (id, closest_point, distance_from_closest_point) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE closest_point=VALUES(closest_point), distance_from_closest_point=VALUES(distance_from_closest_point)")
        cursor.executemany(sql, update_list)
        con.commit()
        print("done")
```

This code outputs the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **update_list** needs to be a tuple of tuples, so you just need to convert it to that before calling **cursor.executemany**. Example below:

```
update_list = tuple([tuple(row) for row in update_list])
con = pymysql.connect('connection settings here')
with con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = ("INSERT INTO properties (id, closest_point, distance_from_closest_point) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE closest_point=VALUES(closest_point), distance_from_closest_point=VALUES(distance_from_closest_point)")
        cursor.executemany(sql, update_list)
        con.commit()
        print("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

try editing code from:

```
cursor.executemany(sql, update_list)
```

to:

```
cursor.executemany(sql, update_list.all())
```